# IIS 7.5 - Authentication works with IP Adress but NOT with FQDN

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, internet-explorer, ntlm

I'm using an IIS Server and run into the following problem:

Using Internet Explorer, I type `http://1.2.3.4/mySite/` and everything works fine, it uses my Windows credentials. When I try `http://name/mySite/` or `http://name.domain.tld/mySite` it does not work.

But what does not work?
I will be asked for my user credentials, but when I type them in and try to login it's going to prompt again and again.. Any quick ideas about what could be the configuration issue?

I already added the site to the local intranet sites.

Comment: What is `name` or `name.domain.tld` actually resolving to on the computer this is happening on? Are you trying to test locally? If so its most likely translating to IPv6 and your IIS binding is strictly set to IPv4.

Answer (score 2):

ON the server, you want `DisableStrictNameChecking` and `DisableLoopbackCheck` registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
```

Add a new DWORD.
The name is `DisableStrictNameChecking`, and the value should be set to **1**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
```

Add a new DWORD
The name is `DisableLoopbackCheck`, and the value should be set to **1**

Restart after setting both.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it should be noted that disabling these settings does open the door for exploits that use them. In development it is fine, but I'd rather not tempt fate in production.